# Introverted and being a part of a community

Tags: shabbat, friendship

To fully exercise orthodox jewish life means being part of a community.

My wife is an introvert who is very involved in giving back to the community but has struggled to make friends and feels very unhappy being alone on shabbos and the loneliness in general.

I am a physician and work a lot and am an introvert as well and so am at a loss of how to help her.

When we host we enjoy the company but she feels she has no friends.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, I fail to see a question, please edit to make a clearer question.

Comment: A common problem these days, sadly. I wish we could offer help, but alas this is beyond our scope, wish and pray for you and your wife much hatzlacha in finding friends, as with all the lonely in Klal Yisrael